# ng-table variable hold count of currently view-able items

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ngtable

Does the ng-table (NgTableParams) have a variable which allows you to find how many items are currently view-able (those items which have not been filtered out)? This includes the items which can be viewed by user (not filtered out) but might be on a page not currently being viewed.

It is not the full length of the dataset, ngTable.count(), nor ngTable.settings().counts. I've looked at these variables/structures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like that [total](http://ng-table.com/api-docs/classes/ngtableparams.html#total) is what you looking for.
From ng-table documentation on the total function:

> Returns the count of the data rows that match the current filter

Comment: just for more information than most people wanted, I was playing around with the ng-table and it looks like myNgTable.data.length will give you the same results (i thought data.length would tell you how much data you originally pushed into the table).